# Flex: Syntax Error expecting right brace before right paren

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I've written a function which gives me the above error. i checked it but i am not able to find the error. I wrote the following code

```
public function calculateTotal():void
{
var len:int=inv_dg.dataProvider.length;

for(var i:int=0;i<len;i++)
{
var dgObj:InvoicePrintRTObject=inv_dg.dataProvider.getItemAt(i) as InvoicePrintRTObject;
var tmp:String=dgObj.quantity.toString();
var tmpqty:Array=tmp.split(",");
var tmpqtytotal:String="";
for(var j:int=0;j<tmpqty.length;j++)
tmpqtytotal+=tmpqty[j]; 
var tmpLotTot:String=dgObj.lottotal.toString();
var tmpTot:Array=tmpLotTot.split(",");
var tmpLottotal:String="";
for(j:int=0;j<tmpTot.length;j++)
tmpLottotal+=tmpTot[j];     
}
totQty.text=""+tmpqtytotal;
totInv.text=""+tmpLottotal;
var cTaxRate=parseInt(ctaxRate.text);
var cTaxAmt=totalInvoice*(cTaxRate/100);
totCTax.text=""+cTaxAmt;
totFinal.text=""+(totalInvoice+cTaxAmt);

}
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: If you turn on the debugger, it would take you 10 seconds to find out by yourself.

Comment: uh actually that's a compile time  error so I don't think the debugger will help him, but the compiler should give you some sort of line number.  Believe your problem is in your second loop you have j:int it should just say j=0; no :int

Comment: @shaunhusain, that's a syntax error so it should be caught by the compiler. Even if it wasn't, enabling the debugger would indeed give a line number. I'm always amazed at the number of Flex/Flash questions that could be solved just by enabling the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second for loop j=0; remove :int

Comment: This isn't really going to help anyone else so feel free to just delete the question if this helps you.